# Unreferencing deleted data from firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and type/javascript, so I am learning as I go. Currently, I am needing to delete an "Event", but as I do I get the error of

"null is not an object (evaluating '_this.currentEvent.is = eventSnapshot.key')

I understand WHY I'm getting this error, but I'm not sure as to how I am to go about it. As I delete the page I am still referencing the (now deleted) data that was previously read from firebase. I've tried things such as

```
this.navCtrl.pop().then( continue => {
   //delete
});
```

but still no luck as it's obviously not a viable workaround. Again, I am still learning so try not roast me too hard. I will paste my relevant code below:

**EventDetailPage where delete functionality is located**

```
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Vehicle Details</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons end>

              <button ion-button icon-only (click)="delete(currentEvent)">

                  <ion-icon name="ios-trash-outline"></ion-icon>
                </button>


          </ion-buttons>
      </ion-navbar>
```

```
<ion-card-content text-wrap>
    <h2>Year:
        <strong>{{currentEvent.year}}</strong>
      </h2>
  <h2>Make:
    <strong>{{currentEvent.make}}</strong>
  </h2>
  <h2>Model:
    <strong>{{currentEvent.model}}</strong>
  </h2> <br> 
 <ion-item id = "pic"><img [src] = "currentEvent.img"></ion-item> <br>
  <h2>Additional information: </h2>


  <ion-item *ngIf="currentEvent.data !== null" >
    <p *ngFor="let bit of currentEvent.data" >
    <strong>{{bit}}</strong><br>
  </p> 
</ion-item>

</ion-card-content>
```

**EventDetailPage ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EventProvider } from '../../providers/event/event';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';


@IonicPage({
    segment: 'event-detail/:eventId'
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-event-detail',
  templateUrl: 'event-detail.html'
})
export class EventDetailPage {
 public currentEvent: any = {};
  public guestName: string = '';
  public guestPicture: string = null;
  public onLoad: boolean = true;
  rootPage: any;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public eventProvider: EventProvider,
   public cameraPlugin: Camera
   ) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    if(this.onLoad){
      this.eventProvider
      .getEventDetail(this.navParams.get('eventId'))
      .on('value', eventSnapshot => {
        this.currentEvent = eventSnapshot.val();
        this.currentEvent.id = eventSnapshot.key;
      });
    }else{
      this.rootPage = TabsPage;
    }

  }

 delete(eventId){
   this.onLoad = false;
   this.navCtrl.pop().then(result => {
    return this.eventProvider.delete(eventId.id);
    }).catch(err => {
      alert(err);
          });

}
}
```

**EventProvier ts where some firebase functions are, not so needed**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Reference, ThenableReference } from '@firebase/database-types';
import {storage} from 'firebase';


@Injectable()
export class EventProvider {
  public eventListRef: Reference;
  //public eventListRefKey?: String


  constructor() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.eventListRef = firebase
          .database()
          .ref(`/userProfile/${user.uid}/eventList`);
      }

    });
  }

  getEventList(): Reference {
    return this.eventListRef;
  }


  createEvent(
    vehYear: string,
    vehMake: string,
    vehModel: string,
    vehVIN: string,
    date: string
  ): ThenableReference {
    return this.eventListRef.push({
      year: vehYear,
      make: vehMake,
      model: vehModel,
      vin: vehVIN,
      date: date
    });
  }

  createArray(
    dataArray: string[],
    vehYear: string,
    vehMake: string,
    vehModel: string,
    vehVIN: string,
    date: string,
    imgResult: string,
  ): ThenableReference{
    this.storeImage(imgResult,vehVIN);
    return this.eventListRef.push({
      data: dataArray,
      year: vehYear,
      make: vehMake,
      model: vehModel,
      vin: vehVIN,
      date: date,
      img: imgResult
    })
  }

  createArrayNoImg(
    dataArray: string[],
    vehYear: string,
    vehMake: string,
    vehModel: string,
    vehVIN: string,
    date: string
  ): ThenableReference{
    return this.eventListRef.push({
      data: dataArray,
      year: vehYear,
      make: vehMake,
      model: vehModel,
      vin: vehVIN,
      date: date,
      img: "https://dy98q4zwk7hnp.cloudfront.net/Dealer-2624-f4ea52f79fddd47068203c3cebc846d0.jpg?type=fit&w=335"
    })
  }

  storeImage(imgResult: string, vin: string){
    const pictures = storage().ref('pictures/'+ vin + '/' + new Date().getTime());
    pictures.putString(imgResult,'data_url');
  }

  getEventDetail(eventId: string): Reference {

    return this.eventListRef.child(eventId);
  }

  delete(eventId: string){
    return this.eventListRef.child(eventId).remove();

  }

  //delete(eventId: string):Reference{
    //return this.eventListRef.remove(eventId);
  //}

}
```

Comment: I added chat functionality to the app as well. But onclick of the chat group, I pass the chatNodeId. I can easily delete the chat groups that way since I'm not necessarily referencing that firebase node from the actual page I'm deleting it from. I know I can probs apply this to the EventPage but I still would like how else i could go about it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `.ts`, always check for `this.currentEvent`, before referencing `this.currentEvent.something`:

```
if(this.currentEvent){
console.log(this.currentEvent.something)
}
```

In `.html`, use `?`:

```
<h2>Year:
    <strong>{{currentEvent?.year}}</strong>
</h2>
```

OR  use ngIf:

```
<h2>Year:
   <span *ngIf='currentEvent'>
    <strong>{{currentEvent.year}}</strong>
   </span>

</h2>
```

**Edit**
Make sure you fix this line:

```
this.currentEvent = eventSnapshot.val();
this.currentEvent.id = eventSnapshot.key;
```

to

```
this.currentEvent = eventSnapshot.val();
if(this.currentEvent){
    this.currentEvent.id = eventSnapshot.key;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and suggestions! I tried all three just now, but unfortunately they didn't work :(

Comment: See my edits in the answer. Are you sure you fixed that line?

Comment: Oops, just barely seeing it. I tried and it works great! I applied the same to the userProfile.key line as well since the error was rolling over. Now I'm having the issue of having to press the delete icon TWICE before the data actually deletes. So I'll go into the event detail page and delete, and it just pops me back to the home page without deleting anything. Then trying again, it works perfectly after. smh..